# Securing ASP.Net Web API with API Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, restful-architecture

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 Web API application where this application will be the source data for different Mobile/Web client apps.  I need to authenticate a user so I can return the correct set of content for the user.  I'm thinking about using an API Key that is sent to every request of my Web API application.  The API Key identifies the user.  I found this post that outlines a potential solution: [From API Key to User with ASP.NET Web API](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/api-key-user-aspnet-web-api)

I need to support forms authentication as well as oAuth 2.0 for Facebook, Twitter, etc.  All of these approaches yield a token I can use to send back and forth from the different clients to my Web API so I can identify the user.  I understand Facebook access tokens expire.  I'm a little confused on what's the best way to deal with Facebook interactions.  Which of the following paths is the best way to go:

1. Rely on the different client apps to authenticate against Facebook (and other oAuth providers) to establish a Facebook access token that's then forwarded to my Web API application?  This means all of the clients are responsible for making sure the Facebook access token is not expired.  The Web API app assumes the access token is always valid.  This seems dangerous to me.  The different apps would authenticate the user then send user information to WebAPI app to register the user in order for the user to consume the data from my Web API app.  This seems like a lot of duplication.
2. Make my Web API application solely responsible for interacting with Facebook (and other oAuth providers) on behalf of all the different client apps using my Web API.  So this approach seems to suggest I need to build some sort of authenticating UI for my Web API app.  I know ASP.Net MVC Web API can have views and front end stuff, but it always seems to me that you are mixing things together.  It seems Web API apps should be singularly focused on returning data.  Users from all of the different client apps will register with my Web Api app by either filling out a registration form, or using Facebook, Twitter, etc.  Is it OK to mix UI views in with a pure REST Web API application?  Then you have to start worrying about everything that goes with UIs on different devices, etc.
3. Is there another way I'm not seeing?

I really appreciate any guidance and links to examples you might have.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you below approach: 
1. Create an authentication API which will authenticate the user. If user is authenticated successfully, create a session (self implemented, may be a record in your db) for that user.

2. Next time user call your other APIs which returns content for that user. In this case it would be must for that user to provider the session id (which you have created in first step) to get the content. If sessionId provided by user does not exist at your end, it means the user is not authenticated. In this case you can return authentication error message to the user telling that he needs to get authenticated first. It is very flexible, scaleable solution in a way that you can store many information regarding that user session. Also once authenticated, user does not need to get authenticated every time he calls your other APIs to get content. It would save you as well from authenticating the user every time.

Comment: You can call it APIKey which I termed as SessionId.

Comment: So are you suggesting my Web API app have some form of UI views where the user enters username/password or gets authenticated vie Facebook etc?  So, a client app tries to access my Web API, Web API realizes the user is not authenticated and redirects them to a login page.  Wouldn't you get into crossdomain issues?  Or would you rely on the client app to do the authentication (UI views)?

Comment: @Tom, I am suggesting that you take the credentials from the user in first API call (via your UI or your authentication API which calls facebook authentication API internally), authenticate the user, create the session at your end, serve the client from the API calls next on-wards. This approach is used by global ticket bookings providers and I find this very good solution.